# Construction of the Lebesgue-Stieltjes measure with monotone r.c. function

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I'm studying the construction of the Lebesgue-Stieltjes measure in Folland's real analysis text, and there's a claim in a theorem that I'm having trouble with.

He first proves the following proposition:

> **Proposition:** Let $F:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be increasing and right continuous. If $(a_j, b_j]$, $(j=1, ..., n)$, are disjoint h-intervals, let $$
> \mu_0(\bigcup_{n =1}^n (a_j, b_j]) = \sum_{j=0}^n [F(b_j)-F(a_j)], \\$$
>   and let $\mu_0(\emptyset) = 0. $ Then $\mu_0$ is a premeasure on the collection of finite disjoint unions of h-intervals.

I'm comfortable with this proposition, but I don't understand how he then uses it to conclude the following:

> **Theorem:** If $F:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is any increasing, right continuous function, there is a unique Borel measure $\mu_F$ on $\mathbb{R}$ such that $\mu_F((a,b]) = F(b) - F(a)$ for all $a, b$.

I understand that the proposition guarantees a unique Borel measure such that $\mu_F(\bigcup_{n =1}^n (a_j, b_j]) = \sum_{j=0}^n [F(b_j)-F(a_j)]$ (since the restriction of outer measure to the domain of the premeasure is equal to the premeasure). I also understand that the unique Borel measure I've just described will happen to agree with  $\mu_F((a,b]) = F(b) - F(a)$.

What I don't understand is why we know that there is at most one Borel measure that agrees with $\mu_F((a,b]) = F(b) - F(a)$. Why isn't there some other $\mu_0$ construction that differs from the equation in the proposition, induces a Borel measure $\mu_F$, and also yields $\mu_F((a,b]) = F(b) - F(a)$?

Comment: Please clarify. Is it the uniqueness part you don't understand?

Comment: Yup, just the uniqueness part. If I understand the claim correctly, there is exactly one Borel measure that agrees with μ_F((a,b])=F(b)−F(a).

Answer (score 1):

Suppose there are two measures $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ that satisfy $\mu_1((a,b]) = \mu_2((a,b]) $ but there exists a measurable set $A$, such that $\mu_1(A) \neq \mu_2(A)$. Let $\nu$ denote $\mu_1-\mu_2$. Then $\nu((a,b])=0$ for any $a,b$. Since $\mathbb R = \bigcup_{n\in \mathbb Z} (n,n+1]$ we have 
$$ \nu(A) = \sum_{n\in \mathbb Z}\nu(A\cap (n,n+1]) =0 $$
due to the monotonicity of the measure. This is a contradiction, since $0\neq \mu_1(A)-\mu_2(A) = \nu(A) =0$.

Comment: thanks for this. the result just wasn't obvious to me... is there something in the theorem that makes this pretty obvious, or is it something that ought to be explicitly proven?

Comment: well the fact that one fixes all the values $\mu((a,b])$ for any $a,b$ is what makes it unique. It is not trivial at all.